# Not being able to boot eOS6 (Odin)

Tags: boot, release-odin

After the fix of the UEFI problem on the official ElementaryOS 6 ISO, I flashed my USB using Rufus as usual. When booting the machine with that USB I get some random black screens indicating that something has occurred and I can't boot into the OS.

1. The image is not corrupted as I used it to create a VM and verified its checksum.
2. I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming and the BIOS is on its last version (currently at 1.14.0).
3. The outputs of the boot are random and are displayed in the images below. (I could only upload one image here, the package containing two images is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtYcv.jpg).
4. I've tried to burn the ISIO using dd, Etcher and manually coping files over a FAT32 GPT partition.

[image: random 1]

Comment: The `No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR` message indicated there’s an issue in the UEFI, but this does seem to happen with Dell notebooks on occasion. Is Elementary properly installed on the machine? Or are you planning on reinstalling it?

Comment: I have Hera installed with no problems

Comment: @matigo I didn't know that it was an issue with the UEFI. Is there any workaround that problem?

Comment: Related: https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-Developer-Systems/DMAR-Firmware-Bug-No-firmware-reserved-region-can-cover-this/td-p/7778874